# jquery -Remeber loaded content to div after refresh

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I am loading content to div and need keep it loaded after page refresh. After some search i would like to use with help of cookie. I used what i found store cookie then load cookie but it's wrong still.

**jquery**

```
$('.linklo').click(function(e){    
    $.cookie('the_cookie', $(this).attr('href')); //save  href to cookie
    if( !empty($.cookie('the_cookie'))){ //if cookie not empty use it          
        $("#LoadMe").load($.cookie('the_cookie')); 
        e.preventDefault();
    } else { // otherwise use href if defined    
        $("#LoadMe").load($(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**html**

```
<div id="LoadMe"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with code which sets the `cookie` value. Please don't set it directly. Set it only if its is empty or null like follows:

```
$('.linklo').click(function(e){
    if( !empty($.cookie('the_cookie'))){      //if cookie not empty  use it
        $("#LoadMe").load($.cookie('the_cookie')); 
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
    else {       // otherwise use href if defined
        $.cookie('the_cookie', $(this).attr('href'));  //save  href to cookie
        $("#LoadMe").load($(this).attr('href'));
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: this is probably better, but content is not loaded in div. It's redirected to page with content

Comment: how the page is getting redirected. We don't have any code like `window.location = ...` I don't think its because of above code. Try and debug at which point page redirect is happening.

Comment: It's calling zend framework action (/web/detail/id). But after click on link it shows only detail html without header and footer. so jquery script probably executed the href, but did not load to div.

Comment: could you please try calling `$("#LoadMe").empty();` before `.load(` call?

Answer (score 0):

It's not using the Cookie method as you've suggested, but I've had great success storing persistent data using HTML5's Local Storage capability.  There are some example of how to use it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).